# Finding row positions through datetime index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has a DateTimeIndex and an X 2d numpy array which is just the values of that dataframe. I want to select some rows through the index of the dataframe

```
dataset[from_d:to_d]
```

Where from_d and to_d are Timestamps. The dataset is sliced just fine but I need to get the positions of those rows inside the dataset. I need them because then I want to select the same rows in the X numpy array. Something like

```
X[indexes]
```

I have tried `np.where(dataset[from_d:to_d])[0]` but it gives me somehow a (23149590,) array when the dataset is of shape: (15075, 13117). Is there a better way to do this than with where?.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (dataset)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
2017-04-12  9

from_d = '2017-04-05'
to_d = '2017-04-10'
print (dataset[from_d:to_d])
            a
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7

indexes = dataset.index.get_indexer(dataset[from_d:to_d].index)
print (indexes)
[2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Or [`Index.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
indexes = dataset.index.searchsorted(dataset[from_d:to_d].index)
print (indexes)
[2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

EDIT:

For not unique DatetimeIndex is it possible with unique index and [`Index.get_indexer_for`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10) 
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(20)}, index=rng.append(rng)).sort_index()
print (dataset)
             a
2017-04-03   0
2017-04-03  10
2017-04-04   1
2017-04-04  11
2017-04-05   2
2017-04-05  12
2017-04-06   3
2017-04-06  13
2017-04-07   4
2017-04-07  14
2017-04-08   5
2017-04-08  15
2017-04-09   6
2017-04-09  16
2017-04-10  17
2017-04-10   7
2017-04-11  18
2017-04-11   8
2017-04-12   9
2017-04-12  19
```

---

```
from_d = '2017-04-05'
to_d = '2017-04-10'

i = dataset[from_d:to_d].index.unique()
print (i)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-05', '2017-04-06', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-08',
               '2017-04-09', '2017-04-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

indexes = dataset.index.get_indexer_for(i)
print (indexes)
[ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Verify indexes:

```
print (dataset.iloc[indexes])
             a
2017-04-05   2
2017-04-05  12
2017-04-06   3
2017-04-06  13
2017-04-07   4
2017-04-07  14
2017-04-08   5
2017-04-08  15
2017-04-09   6
2017-04-09  16
2017-04-10  17
2017-04-10   7
```

Comment: I had to use the searchsorted option. I had to do this because there are duplicate timestamps in the index and get_indexer was throwing an exception.

Comment: @Brandon - It working correctly? Because I test it in `rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(20)}, index=rng.append(rng)).sort_index()` and not sure it it is expected `[ 4  4  6  6  8  8 10 10 12 12 14 14]`

Comment: Actually, you are right. It does not work as there are duplicates. Any alternatives?